# Apexchart max yaxis value for polarArea chart

Tags: angular, apexcharts

I want to set a max value of 100 for the polarArea chart on Apexcharts.

I've used a max value on the yaxis element for other charts, but it doesn't work on the polarChart:

```
  yaxis: {
    max: 100,
  },
```

Looks like Apex sets the max value based on the largest number in the series this is a screenshot of the chart with a single series value of 80:

[image]

How do I force the chart to always show a 0 - 100 range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a bug in ApexCharts. I have fixed it in this [commit](https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/commit/5f37ff7cb5f169f7bb44f747c8ddcd5876369408) and the fix will be released along with the next version 3.22.1